# {...x.d} === x.d Compairsion giving error

Tags: javascript

I was trying to follow code in the Chrome console when I encountered puzzling behavior.

```
var x = {d: {a: 1}, b: 3, c: "hello"}
{...x.d} === x.d // gives an error in the chrome console [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...']
x.d === {...x.d} // gives expected as false
({...x.d} === x.d)
```

Why is the first comparison a syntax error without any parenthesis?
It works if I put it inside a console.log({...x.d} === x.d).

Can someone point me in the direction of what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A code parser doesn't look ahead of what is meaningful. What it has: the current context (for example the current character of code inside a string literal). What it does: interprets the current code based on the current context (state).

So in your case it encounters `{` with the context being outside statement or expression so `{` is interpreted as a block's start. The next spread syntax doesn't have sense so a syntax error is thrown.

When you add `(` you change the context to an expression so the following `{` is interpreted as object literal or destructuring.

Comment: thankyou so much for your reply. I am not an expert in compilers and code parsers, but still thinking out loud, parsers should do a speculative parsing first, '{' could mean the start of the block or the start of an object literal.
Then settle for the correct tree branch. If it lands on more than one correct branch, then grammar is not precise. Ideally, this way of parsing a grammar should lead to a correct evaluation of such a statement.

Comment: @soumitra seems parsers don't look ahead much ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Thank you so much for helping. Still, in 2024, someone should have thought of this, and there is still some research left on this.

Comment: @soumitra error handling like that in a parser is, perhaps surprisingly, very very difficult. JavaScript in particular has an extremely complicated grammar. It all hinges on the token at the beginning of a new statement, and speculatively parsing beyond that is something that no parser for the language currently does. It can take a lot of tokens after the `{` to discover what production in the grammar is supposed to be recognized.

Comment: @Pointy, thank you for your reply; backtracking is regular for token parsing, right? For example, var variable = 10 would at one point see 'var'(iable still left to parse). At this time, it will have something where it can say syntax error, but it does not and parses further to find out it is the correct token composition. Why does it not work for all such cases?

Comment: @soumitra a parser can't be fast and smart at the same time. for example JSON has a strict format (more strict that JS') so it could parse fast. we have megabytes of JS loaded on a web page nowadays, imaging if a JS parser would be smart but slower. that's why JSON.parse is significantly faster than eval()

Comment: @soumitra that's a good question, but usually (deffo not always) parsing is a two-layer thing: the "base" layer splits up the source into tokens (operators, "words", things like `{` and `(` and `;` etc), and then the "parser" layer works on those. So the example you gave doesn't really happen because `var` and `variable` are not going to be confused by the base layer (usually called the "lexer" or "lexical analyzer"). Yes, parsers can back-track, but again JavaScript is extremely complicated in its grammar.